# Sticky div inside fixed positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need to place a `div` which should be sticky on scrolling of parent `div` which is positioned to `fixed`. Please check the below code snippet.

```
<style>
   .outer{
     width:300px;
     height:400px;
     border:1px solid red;
     overflow:auto;
     position:fixed;
     top:50px;
     left:100px;
   }
   .tag{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:80px;
    background:#ffcc33;
    border:2px solid #dfa800;
    border-top:0px;
    padding:3px 5px;
   }
   .inner{
     height:800px;
     border:1px solid green;
     margin:0px 5px;
   }
 </style>

 <div  class="outer"> <!-- This is scroll-able-->
   <div class="tag">Click here to Refresh</div><!-- This should be sticky-->
   <div class="inner"><!--This content causes scrolling-->
      Inner content...........
   </div>
 </div>
```

So here, `tag` part should be stuck to top of the `outer` div.Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramstheroyal/ce14vcqL/2/)

Is there any workaround to achieve this with pure css.

Comment: did you tried using position:fixed on .tag?

Comment: Could you, please, mark the answer as correct, if it realy is?

Comment: @sagarkodte Yes, But I have to keep fixed top to the inner div as well which I didn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try introducing a wrapper div around the tag - this way you can separate the positioning logic on the wrapper, and set the tag to `position: fixed;` for stickiness. Note that `position: fixed;` by itself on the tag will pull it out of its normal dom flow, so you need to adjust its positioning.

HTML

```
<div class="tag-wrapper">
    <div class="tag">Click here to Refresh</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tag-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 80px;
}

.tag {
    position: fixed;
    background: #ffcc33;
    border: 2px solid #dfa800;
    border-top: 0px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

[click to see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drscodelab/67o9rowo/)

Comment: The code in the answer is different from the code in the fiddle. And why would you create this .tag-wrapper for? it's just redundant.

Answer (score 4):

The only approach I see with the css is to put the tag to position fixed and just allign it the same as the parent div.

Like this:

```css
.outer {
     width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     overflow: auto;
     position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
     left: 100px;
   }
   
   .tag {
     position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
     left: 180px;
     background: #ffcc33;
     border: 2px solid #dfa800;
     border-top: 0px;
     padding: 3px 5px;
   }
   
   .inner {
     height: 800px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     margin: 0px 5px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tag">Click here to Refresh</div>
  <div class="inner">
    Inner content...........
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, It worked on chrome. Now in case this fails elsewhere (maybe due to inconsistencies with nested fixed positioning), it will surely work if the tag element does not have to be inside the fixed position element, and can be outside it.

```
   .outer {
     width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     overflow: auto;
     position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
     left: 100px;
   }

   .tag {
     position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
     left: 180px;
     background: #ffcc33;
     border: 2px solid #dfa800;
     border-top: 0px;
     padding: 3px 5px;
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ce14vcqL/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in absolute position, parent should not be the one scrolling, because it will follow the scroll (coordonate 0 remains at top and goes up as the scroll does).

You may just scroll the inner div :

```css
   .outer {
     width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
     left: 100px;
   }
   
   .tag {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 80px;
     background: #ffcc33;
     border: 2px solid #dfa800;
     border-top: 0px;
     padding: 3px 5px;
   }
   
   .inner {
     overflow: auto;
     height: 100%;
     border: 1px solid green;
     margin: 0px 5px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tag">Click here to Refresh</div>
  <div class="inner">
    Inner content...........
    <br/><!-- content needed to show the scroll bar -->
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    end
  </div>
</div>
```

Purpose of my answer is mainly to help you understand how it works :) and that there is in fact no trouble on your initial CSS, just was not the way to do it for the behavior expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the tag outside of the fixed container and fix it at the same position?